# Access to Resources

Tags: c#, resources

I've C# project and it has Resources folder. This folder has some of txt files. This files have various file names.

I'm taking file names from any source as string variable. For example I have fileName string variable and test.txt file in Resources folder:

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
```

When I want to access this file as like below, I can:

```
WpfApplication.Properties.test.txt;
```

But, When I want to access it by this code, I can't.

```
WpfApplication.Properties.fileName;
```

I want to use fileName string variable and access this text file.

What can I do to access it?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :** 
I change form of this question:
I've string variable assigned any text file name. For example; I have a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt, etc.. I'm taking this file name as string variable (fileName) via some loops. So, I took "c.txt" string. And, I can access this file by code in below:

```
textName = "c.txt";
fileName = "../../Resources\\" + textName;
```

However, when I build this project as Setup Project and install .exe file to any PC, there is no "Resources" folder in application's folder. So,

> ../../Resources\

is unavailable.

How can I access Resources folder from exe file's folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Resource File` to your project wich has the extension `.resx`/`.aspx.resx`. You will then be able to double click on this file and edit the required resources/resource strings. To do this **right click on Project node in Solution Explorer** > **Add** > **New Item** > **Resource File**. Let us assume you have added a file called `ResourceStrings.resx` to the `Properties` folder and added a resource string with key name `MyResourceString`, to access these strings you would do

```
string s = Properties.ResourceStrings.MyResourceString;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you taking a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx

If your text files have build action set as Resource you can locate them in code like:
(assuming the file name is fileName and its located in Resources folder)

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("Resources/{0}", fileName), UriKind.Relative);
 System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

Then you can access info.Stream to get access to your file.